# Can we transfer the whole charge of a body to another body?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge, conductors

Today my colleague said:

"If charged body (say 5 Coulomb) is any charged conductor $A$, it can be done by enclosing $A$ completely by second uncharged conductor $B$ and connecting them by a conducting wire. $B$ will acquire 5 Coulomb and $A$ becomes uncharged.

Is this true? Can we transfer the whole charge of a body to another body?

Comment: Remember that the charge always goes to the outer surface of a conductor. When you connect the two spheres they become a single conductor.

Comment: So the surface of "that" single conductor $C$ will be the surface of the larger conductor $B$. So the charge will reside on the outer surface of larger conductor $B$. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Faraday's ice pail experiment was the first precise quantitative experiment on electrostatic charge.

He had an metal ice bucket (pail) which was electrically insulated from the ground connect to a leaf electroscope (a device which measures charge and voltages).
Initially the ice bucket was uncharged and the electroscope showed no reading.

When a charged brass ball suspended from a silk (insulator) thread  was placed inside the ice bucket and touched the inside of the ice bucket the electroscope showed a deflection which did not change when the brass ball was removed from inside the ice bucket.

A subsequent experiment using the electroscope showed that the brass ball had no charge on it so all the charge on the brass ball had been transferred to the ice bucket.

The Wikipedia article [Faraday's ice pail experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_ice_pail_experiment) gives much more information but I particularly like [Faraday's communication to R, Phillips](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Zj2mMkQsZgkC&pg=PA200&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) in February 1843.

Comment: Thanks... I will have to give a reading to the Faraday-R. Phillips article... By the way as John Rennie pointed out : "The charge always goes to the outer surface of a conductor. When we connect the two conductors $A$ and $B$ by a conducting wire, the whole system becomes a single conductor. So the surface of "that" single conductor $C$ will be the surface of the larger conductor $B$. So the whole charge will reside on the outer surface of larger conductor $B$. Then we can remove the conducting wire. Thus we can transfer the whole charge of a conductor to another conductor."

Comment: Do you think the reasoning is correct?